# How did Euclid arrive at law of reflection $r=i$?

Tags: visible-light, reflection, geometric-optics, history

The law of reflection, $r=i$, is attributed to Euclid. In his Optics text he refers to it under Graph 19 and says he has demonstrated it in his Catoptrics. But I do not understand his reasoning in Catoptrics. (To make the matter more confusing, some historians claim Catoptrics was written by another person several hundred years after Euclid.)

Did Euclid have a concept of ``shortest distance'' for the light path? How else could he come to the conclusion that $r=i$?

Comment: Observation? Laws are distillates of observations AFAIK. The are like axioms, assumed.

Comment: May also be well-suited to [HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com).